# In Windows, is there a way to get a notification when a new MIDI port is available?

Tags: c++, windows, midi

In Windows, is there a way to get a notification when a new MIDI port is available?

Is there a better solution that polling the list of ports?

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more about what *a new MIDI port is available* means (for those of us not in the biz)? Are you referring to (electronic) keyboards or hot-pluggable output devices or something else?

Comment: Yes, I want to be notified when either a USB MIDI keyboard, USB MIDI interface, Firewire MIDI interface is either connected or disconnected from the machine. Anything that would cause midiInGetNumDevs() or midiOutGetNumDevs() to return a different value.

Answer (score 1):

Your window could listen for [WM_DEVICECHANGE messages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363480.aspx) with the `DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL` event, but that data might or might not be useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

The Windows Runtime API provides a device watcher:
[Windows Runtime API  Windows.Devices.Enumeration  DeviceInformation CreateWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.enumeration.deviceinformation.createwatcher?view=winrt-22621). The watcher sends events when a device is added, updated, or removed.

It's most convenient to use the AQS filter variety with the selector from MidiInPort::GetDeviceSelector or MidiOutPort::GetDeviceSelector.

The provided IDs are used to open the device using MidiInPort and MidiOutPort::FromIdAsync.